# Limit involving modified Bessel Function of the second kind

Tags: limits-and-convergence, bessel-functions

I'm looking for the following limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\text{BesselK}^{(2,0)}(0,x)}{\text{BesselK}(0,x)}}}{\log (x)}$$

I believe the limit is finite, and is near -0.578. However, it is hard to get more digits numerically, and I'm interested in knowing if there is a closed form behind this constant.

$\text{BesselK}^{(2,0)}$ is the second derivative of the Bessel K function with respect to its first variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using series representations, it turns out to be $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$